Node cluster: only last process being used
Before asking, I should notice that I've read very similar question but still obtain negative result on my PC on Windows. Thus, need to ask it again.
I have two .js files, in respect to cluster and worker functionality. The worker has two endpoint: /fast that replies immideatelly and /heavy that has delay for 5 seconds.
Cluster:
import os from "os";
import cluster from "cluster";
cluster.setupPrimary({
  exec: "./worker.js",
});
for (let i = 0; i < os.cpus().length; i++) {
  cluster.fork();
}

Worker:
import express from "express";
const app = express();
app.get("/fast", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Fast completed! pid=${process.pid}`);
});
app.get("/heavy", (req, res) => {
  const time = Date.now();
  while(Date.now() - time < 5000){}
  res.send(`Heavy completed! pid=${process.pid}`);
});
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log(`App started, pid=${process.pid}`)
});

Due to the information from os.cpus().length, my PC uses 12 CPUs. Thus, 12 Express servers are forked and work in parallel:
> node ./cluster.js
App started, pid=23240
App started, pid=36108
App started, pid=8900
App started, pid=12640
App started, pid=24648
App started, pid=17112
App started, pid=24232
App started, pid=16088
App started, pid=36240
App started, pid=21488
App started, pid=25748
App started, pid=10496

Now I'm executing the first request to the /heavy endpoint, then almost immediatelly the second request to /fast endpoint using two separate terminals.
> curl http://localhost:3000/heavy
Heavy completed! pid=10496

> curl http://localhost:3000/fast
Fast completed! pid=10496

In my case, I need to wait while the request /fast executing relatively the same amount of time, as the request to the /heavy endpoint. It is logically, because as I see that both requests are served by the same process with pid=10496.
The question is: Why both requests are served by the same process? The enpoint /heavy is obviosly still executing, when I send the second request to /fast. Then, why the load balancer from cluster.js does not route the second request to another process?
Node.js version is 20.13.1, if it's important.

You can use pm2 instead
